# How to stop Terminal from asking for access to some folders?

Tags: catalina

Since upgrade to Catalina, even when I login as myself, `terminal` prompts for these kind of permissions.

[image]

How can I grant these permissions once and for all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is likely that you need to give terminal "Full disk access."

1. Open up System Preferences and go to the Security & Privacy icon and click on it.
2. Click on the last tab "Privacy
3. Click on the padlock icon in lower left corner of that window
4. Note that Terminal may already be in the list and not checked, if it is check it
5. If it is not click the "+" button and navigate to the /Applications/Utilities folder and select the Terminal.app
6. Once it is added, if it is not already checked, check it and close System Preferences.

Mine looks like this.
[image: System preferences > Privacy]